# Не запускается IDEA из командной строки

Tags: bash, intellij-idea

Пытаюсь запустить проект в Intellij IDEA из командной строки(GitBash) при помощи команды idea.

Но выдаёт сообщение:

> "No JVM installation found. please install a 32-bit JDK. If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in computer > system properties > system settings> environment variables."

> "NOTE: We have detected that you are running a 64-bit version of the Windows operating system, but are running the 32-bit executable. This can prevent you from finding a 64-bit installation of Java. Consider running the 64-bit version instead, if this is the problem you're encountering."

У меня установлено java 13, переменные среды все определены, помогите разобраться в чём дело???

Прилагаю 2 скриншота чтобы было понятней:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если я правильно помню, то запустить ее прям бинарником нелья, там рядом валяется специальный батник, который выставляет все нужные переменные среды и запускает.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что ответ кроется в этом сообщении, проверьте разрядность системы и приложения и убедитесь, что они соответствуют друг-другу.

> "NOTE: We have detected that you are running a 64-bit version of the
> Windows operating system, but are running the 32-bit executable. This
> can prevent you from finding a 64-bit installation of Java. Consider
> running the 64-bit version instead, if this is the problem you're
> encountering."

Comment: Это понятно))), но как в итоге решить проблему???

Comment: Вероятнее всего вам нужно будет скачать 64-битовую версию идеи)

Comment: спасибо за совет! Но у меня уже была установлена  64 битная....